# linq to sql ExecuteQuery() as IQueryable

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

ExecuteQuery() method returns an IEnumerable but is there a way to make it return IQueryable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you can call `AsQueryable`, but it won't do any good. The problem is that when you use `ExecuteQuery`, the query isn't *composable* because LINQ to SQL doesn't "understand" it as such.

One of the core purposes of `IQueryable<T>` is to allow the various aspects of a query to be composed together and then LINQ to SQL can convert them into a single SQL query. That just doesn't work when one of the bits of the query is effectively opaque.

Comment: You seem to understand my exact problem. Is there any way around this if I want to use ad-hoc queries?

Comment: Not if you want to use them as part of other queries, as far as I'm aware. It's possible you could write a stored procedure and call *that* in a composable way, providing the SQL as a parameter, but it would be pretty horrible.

Comment: Would this theoretically work as far as just the skip and take operators? I know they wouldn't be fed to the db, but would the underlying reader just grab those instead of reading the whole set into memory?

Comment: @Maslow: I'm not sure what you mean. But if you're talking about taking an `IEnumerable<T>`, then using `AsQueryable().Skip(...).Take(...)`, that's not going to pass the skip/take part to the database.

Comment: right, but I mean the underlying `SqlDbDataReader`, does the skip and take help that guy in this situation? I guess not since each get next would call the mapping code to a real type, and it's not seekable. Perhaps it would increase for all the items after your skip take, by disposing/closing the reader instead of mapping them?

Comment: @Maslow: I don't really know what you mean - `SqlDataReader` doesn't implement `IDataReader`, so skip and take simply aren't available. Basically if you want to efficiently get to a section of data, you need to put that in the SQL - which is what LINQ to SQL or EF will do for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can export the result of your query to a list, and next convert it to IQueryable. See the next example code:

```
public IQueryable<Data> GetData()
    string query = @"select ...";
    object[] parameters = new object[...]{...};
    var resultQuery = this.DataContext.ExecuteQuery<SICDB.Data>(query, parameters);
    var tempList = resultQuery .ToList();
    return tempList.AsQueryable();
}
```