# Combine Linq2SQL with custom SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

From a custom SQL query I'd like to get an IQueryable (I have my reasons):

Something like:

```
IQueryable<Client> query = Foo<Client>("SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ...");

query.Where(e => e.Active==true).Skip(10).Take(10); //etc.
```

Is there any way to implement Foo?

I found `ExecuteQuery<T>(...).AsQueryable()`, but that doesn't work as it loads all records.

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq to sql ExecuteQuery() as  IQueryable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065241/linq-to-sql-executequery-as-iqueryable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using Dynamic Linq. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Can you put this part of your query in a view?

```
SELECT * FROM Clients...
```

Then you can use LINQ `Where` and `Skip/Take`.

```
var results = db.MyViews.Where(e => e.Active == true).Skip(10).Take(10);
```

Comment: No, to clarify, the SQL is user submitted. (I'm working on a admin tool)

Comment: In that case I would wrap the query in another query to handle paging, you are in the land of dynamic SQL at this point I think. What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* implement this but you'd have to parse the SQL text and look up the mapping to get the correct types (e.g., from *Clients* to `Client`). There's no built-in facility for automatically generating an `IQueryable` from SQL.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the best way would be to implement your own wrapper inheriting IQueryable for such cases. In GetEnumerator() you can implement a row-by-row results reading or simply return ExecuteQuery(...).GetEnumerator() from your own GetEnumerator() method.